# Xcode 4 freezes with a huge # of errors/"issues" in the "Issue Navigator"

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am linking a large set of libraries (Boost) to a C++ project in Xcode 4. Clearly I haven't done it correctly, because I get errors... lots and lots of them. That's not the problem. The problem is that there seems to be no limit to how many errors Xcode dutifully logs as "issues" in its "issue navigator". It occupies all of my RAM with processing 1000+ issues, and eventually of course everything freezes when no more memory is left.

Is there a way to set a limit on the number of 'issues'? Is there someone I can personally beat upside the head with a sizeable stick for programming an IDE in such a way?

Comment: 1)Bashing in public as all very well, but have you filed this as a bug/feature request with Apple? 2)For such a specific problem have you asked at the Apple Developer Forums?

Answer (score 0):

I had a mixed project Objective C and C++ and forgot to rename some imported files from a pure Objective C project from *.m to *.mm thus it couldn't deal with the C++ syntax in included headers.